# How Can I Set Column or Row Span of a Control Programmatically on Universal Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app on Windows 10. I'm trying **change column and row of a control in code stage**. However, I have not found a solution that works. Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use either of these ways :

```
Grid.SetRow(elementToSetOn, rowNumber);
```

or

```
elementToSetOn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
```

Similarly you can set for column also.